# how to set to make automatically import ~ ""?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Hi I'm using Go Lang in Vscode. and I searched about how to set to make possible import something automatically and I tried to add "go.autocompleteUnimportedPackages": true," at settings.json like below. but not works. how to try it?

```
"[go]": {

    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": false
    },
},
"go.formatTool": "gofmt",
"go.autocompleteUnimportedPackages": true,
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
"workbench.settings.enableNaturalLanguageSearch": false,
"go.alternateTools": {

},
```

Comment: just use the go extension/language-server from VS Code market place (extension ID: *golang.go*) it will help with imports, formatting and much more.

Comment: `"source.organizeImports": true` -- that is the default, and it seems like you DISABLED it.